# Can't drop trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created a trigger on a table, and now I can't alter or delete it.
I cant even access the table.
what can I do?

trigger script:

```
create  trigger [Products].[InsertLessThen5InStock]
on [Products].[Products]
after update
as
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ck int

            select UnitsInStock from Products.Products where UnitsInStock<5
    set @ck=@@ROWCOUNT
    print @ck
    if @ck >0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @mails varchar (200)
        exec dbo.Manager_email @mails output
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name =             'DefaultMailSender',
        @recipients =               @mails ,
        @body =                     'Products that will expire in less then 5 days',
        @subject =                  'Products that will expire in less then 5 days',
        @body_format =              'HTML',
        @query =                    'EXECUTE MadCat.dbo.SaveTableAsHTML 
                                @DBFetch =''select UnitsInStock from Products.Products where UnitsInStock<5'''

    END
END
GO
```

Comment: Why can't you alter it or delete it?

Comment: What scripts are you running to try and drop or alter it? What errors are you getting?  What does `i cant even access to the table` mean?  You need to be *much* more specfiic in what your problem is, and what you have tried.

Comment: i tried to delete it throw gui and drop trigger...

Comment: What message do you see when you try to execute DROP TRIGGER?

Comment: it just run and not doing anything while i run drop trigger

Comment: cant even access the table means that i cant even exec select from the table

Comment: Sounds like you don't have ALTER permission for the table, which would prevent you altering the trigger.  To drop a trigger you need ALTER permission on the table the trigger is defined on.

Comment: I wonder if it could be a schema problem.  Are you sure you are looking at [Products].[InsertLessThen5InStock], and not [dbo].[InsertLessThen5InStock] or [SomeOtherSchema].[InsertLessThen5InStock]?

Comment: @Stainy OP says he created the trigger. We have to assume he has permissions.  And there appears to have been no error message.

Comment: i have access.
i done it b4 i created the trigger and no one but me can access this db

Comment: when im trying to delete it using GUI its says "lock request time out period exceeded"

Comment: Single user mode ftw?

Comment: [This post suggests](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=121510) you have hanging connections. Get all the way out of SQL Server Management Studio and everything else that's touching the database, and then go back in and try again.

Comment: i have to say that this for a school project so im the only user on this db i tryed to exit and entering but its not working

Answer (score 2):

Since it is complaining about not being able to get a lock, it means some process has reserved the table exclusively.  You should try restarting the server, and then issuing the drop trigger command.

```
drop trigger [Products].[InsertLessThen5InStock]
```

Comment: if it drop it manually it dosent show nothing just thinking but when im trying to delete it using GUI its says "lock request time out period exceeded"
i have to say that this for a school project so im the only user on this db

Comment: nothing else is working beside this, i closed everything.
i close sql via task manager and then process and then end process tree.
i cant even do select on the table

Comment: You can't do a select because the table is locked by another process.  I would restart SQLServer, and then try dropping the trigger.

Comment: Well, in extremis, try rebooting the machine if that won't interfere with anyone else.